# Is this a typo in the Python Skyfield API? "International Coordinate Reference Frame (ICRF)"?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, celestial-mechanics, coordinates, frames

In the Python Skyfield library there is a position object [`skyfield.positionlib.ICRF`](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/api-position.html#skyfield.positionlib.ICRF), in the documentation it states:

> An (x,y,z) position and velocity oriented to the ICRF axes.
>
> The International Coordinate Reference Frame (ICRF) is a permanent
> reference frame that is the replacement for J2000. Their axes agree to
> within 0.02 arcseconds. It also supersedes older equinox-based systems
> like B1900 and B1950.

From my minimal knowledge in surrounding these topics this look to be a typo? I cannot find a reference or any documentation relating to the "International **Coordinate** Reference Frame" only to the ["International **Celestial** Reference Frame"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Celestial_Reference_System_and_its_realizations).

Also based on what I've read/learned about the International Celestial Reference Frame the documentation from Skyfield seems to be describing just that. Further leading me to believe this is a typo.

Can anyone clarify if the "International **Coordinate** Reference Frame" is an actual thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quotation correctly (though not completely) describes the  International **Celestial** Reference Frame, so I'm comfortable calling "Coordinate" a typo.

Comment: Assuming the OP is somewhat familiar with version control software or using github they should create either a pull request or an issue. Correcting typos is an acceptable commit. The typo Coordinate is used twice in the library and is probably copy-pasted. Otherwise Celestial is used. https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield/blob/b3df7025d1c477f2171dbbb57bd1175a61a2904c/skyfield/framelib.py#L40 https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield/blob/2fcd426936a4968253dd196d436335418318cec9/skyfield/positionlib.py#L81

Comment: Better than a pull request is to submit an issue and make sure it really isn't what the author intended.  Do the pull request after that.